# Cashier (Stripe) integration in Lumen

Tags: php, stripe-payments, lumen, laravel-cashier

I have integrated cashier in laravel 8 without any problem but when I am integrating cashier in lumen 8 it has become a panic process I have spent a lot of time integrating it I even googled everywhere but no luck.
Can anyone help me integrating cashier in lumen 8. what I have done so far is as follow

1. installed cashier by using this command: composer require laravel/cashier
2. then run: php artisan migrate
3. php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cashier-migrations"
4. Added: use *Laravel\Cashier\Billable*; and *use Billable*; in User Model
5. Set stripe api keys in .env file: STRIPE_KEY=my-stripe-key , STRIPE_SECRET=my-stripe-secret
6. in my code when I coded $user->createSetupIntent();

When I execute line#6 I am getting this error

**No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using "Stripe::setApiKey()". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.**

It seems like lumen is unable to read cashier module can anyone help fixing this issue?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Yes by using direct stripe-php library rather than using laravel billable module